# Sharepoint contribute permissions for a library

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-2013

I have used a tool to move over 20 folders into a document library. The tool also moved over the read only rights for the folders. 
Now I have 3 users I need to add so that they have contribute access to all of the folders on that library. But when I go to people and groups all I see is stuff for the home page. I only want to give rights to this document library. Do I break inheritance and give individual permissions to everyone listed in the contribute and read only groups?
I am unsure of how to give contribute rights ONLY to 3 people for 1 document library?

Comment: You will have to break inheritance for the document library and configure the permissions for that document library the way you want. These permissions will flow down to all of the folders in the document library, unless you break inheritance at the folder level.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to break inheritance for the Document Library and configure the permissions for that Document Library the way you want. These permissions will flow down to all of the folders in the Document Library, unless you break inheritance at the folder level.

You may want to consider creating a SharePoint Group, to which you can add the 3 people, and grant the group Contribute rights to the Document Library. That way if you need to change who can access the Document Library, you can just edit the Group membership. I believe that this is best practice.

Comment: But will those with read access on the folders need to be added to the document library permissions set in order to read the documents?

Comment: When you break inheritance, the existing permission aren't lost. You just get the ability to modify them without affecting the Parent's permissions. If there are groups who have read access to the Document Library now, they will still have it afterwards.